# Turning a string with comma values into individual rows of a multi-layered index with Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe which currently looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Film' : ['James Bond: Spectre', 'Avengers: Endgame'],
        'Year' : [2015, 2019],
        'Director(s)': ['Sam Mendes', 'Anthony Russo, Joe Russo'],
        'Actor(s)': ["Daniel Craig, Cristoph Waltz", "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Scarlett Johannson"]})

         Film          | Year |     Director(s)    |        Actor(s)
 ----------------------|------|--------------------|-----------------------
 James Bond: Spectre   | 2015 |     Sam Mendes     |     Daniel Craig,
                       |      |                    |   Christoph Waltz
 ----------------------|------|--------------------|-----------------------
  Avengers: Endgame    | 2019 | Anthony Russo, Joe |   Robert Downey Jr.,   
                       |      |        Russo       | Chris Evans, Scarlett
                       |      |                    |       Johansson
```

I would like to split the actor column and the director column by the commas in each string so that they become multi layered columns in which each new entry occupies a separate cell as per the below:

```
         Film          | Year |     Director(s)   |        Actor(s)
 ----------------------|------|-------------------|----------------------
 James Bond: Spectre   | 2015 |     Sam Mendes    |     Daniel Craig
                       |      |                   |----------------------
                       |      |                   |    Christoph Waltz
 ----------------------|------|-------------------|----------------------
  Avengers: Endgame    | 2019 |   Anthony Russo   |   Robert Downey Jr.
                       |      |                   |----------------------  
                       |      |-------------------|      Chris Evans
                       |      |     Joe Russo     |----------------------
                       |      |                   |  Scarlett Johansson
```

My priority is that the  Director(s) column and the Actor(s) column include each value separately but the multi-layered indices of two columns are not linked - Anthony Russo and Robert Downey Jr. are not intrinsically connected apart from their connection to the same film.

I am fairly new to Python and Pandas so I appreciate this may not be the way multi-indexing works. If there is a more efficient way of organising the data, I would be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I think Pandas' explode() function might solve what you need. See an example here https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/07/pandas-0-25-0-is-here-what-is-new-named-aggregation-explode-and-sparse-dataframe/

Comment: As I understand it, the explode() function will create new rows rather than splitting the columns into a multi-layered index?

Comment: This seem to get close to what you want. (Used "Actor" instead of Actor's) df.assign(Actor=df.Actor.str.split(',')).explode('Actor').set_index(['Film', 'Year'])